# A question on properties of a limit function.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f_n: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ is an increasing sequence of measurable functions where $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and suppose the sequence $ \left( \int_A f_n d \mu \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is bounded. Let $ f : A \rightarrow [0 , \infty] $ be defined by $f(x) = \sup\{ f_n(x) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. I want to show that $f_n \rightarrow f $ pointwise, and also I want to show that $f$ is finite almost everywhere.

For the first bit, let $x \in A$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. If $f(x) = \infty$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) = \infty$. If not, then by definition of supremum there is $ n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $f(x) - \varepsilon < f_{n_0}(x).$ Since $f_n$ is increasing this gives $| f(x) - f_n(x) | < \varepsilon $ for all $n \geq n_0$. Thus $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise.

To show $f$ is finite almost everywhere, first I show that each $f_n$ is finite almost everywhere. Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for $j \in \mathbb{N}$ let $E_j = \{ x \in A \mid f_n(x) \geq j \}$. Then from other results, we have that $\mu\left( E_j\right) \leq \frac{1}{j} \int_E f_n d \mu $. By assumption $\int_A f_n d \mu $ is bounded and so $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}\mu(E_j) = 0$. Note also that $f_n^{-1}\left( \{ \infty \} \right) = \bigcap_{j = 1}^\infty E_j$. Since $(E_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing and $\mu(E_1) < \infty$, we have that $\mu\left( f_n^{-1}\left( \{ \infty \} \right) \right) = \mu\left( \bigcap_{j = 1}^\infty E_j \right) = \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}\mu(E_j) = 0$. Thus each $f_n$ is finite almost everywhere.

And on this part I am stuck, not sure how to show that $f$ is also finite almost everywhere. I suspect I should have to use the fact the sequence $\left( \int_A f_n d \mu \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is bounded.

Comment: This is Beppo Levi's theorem

Answer (score 3):

By Fatou's lemma, we have
$$\int_A f d\mu \le \liminf_n \int_A f_n d\mu $$
and the rhs is bounded by some constant. This implies that $f \in L^1(A)$ and therefore finite almost everywhere.

Comment: Have you redefined $f(x)$ as $ \lim \inf_n f_n(x) $ ? Otherwise, I'm not sure how from Fatou's lemma it follows that $ \int_A \sup f_n d \mu  \leq \lim \inf_n \int_A f_n d \mu $.

Comment: Yes that is it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is not finite almost everywhere. Then there is some set $S\subset A$ with measure $\mu (S)>0$ such that $f_n(x)\to\infty$ on $S$.

But since $f_n(x)\cdot 1_S\leq f_n(x)$ for all $x\in A$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_S f_n(x)dx\leq\int_A f_n(x)dx
\end{align*}
But $\int_A f_n(x)dx$ is bounded, so we have a dominating function $kf_m(x)$ of $f_n(x)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R},m\in\mathbb{N}$.

But $f_n(x)\to\infty$ on $S$, so dominating convergence theorem would give us that $\int_S f_n(x)dx\to\infty$ which implies $\int_A f_n(x)dx\to\infty$. But these integrals are bounded, which is a contradiction.